# Multiple Checkbox selected elements pass to array and from another array show selected as checked in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Am very new to vue js and need a way where I have multiple checkboxes and when I select them an array gets updated with the checked elements with Vue JS.
Eg :

`allcolors = ['Red', 'Blue', 'Green'];`
and I select first two so my

`selectedColors = ['Red', 'Blue'];` 
and then click saves, saves it to database.

When I open the form Red and Blue gets checked fetching record from database.

```
fetchedColors = ['Red', 'Blue'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    items: [
      { label: 'Red', value: 'red' },
      { label: 'Blue', value: 'blue' },
      { label: 'Green', value: 'green' },
    ],
    checkedValues: [],
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <label 
    v-for="(item, index) in items"
    :key="index"
   >
    {{ item.label }}
    <input 
     type="checkbox"
     :value="item.value"
     v-model="checkedValues"
    />
  </label>
  {{ checkedValues }}
</div>
```

Not really sure what you're asking. Do you mean something like this? Check the docs they may help - https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox

Comment: I want to display selected checkboxes on display of form.

Answer (score 1):

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    items: [
      { label: 'Red', checked: true },
      { label: 'Blue', checked: true },
      { label: 'Green', checked: false },
    ],
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <label 
    v-for="(item, index) in items"
    :key="index"
   >
    {{ item.label }}
    <input 
     type="checkbox"
     :checked="item.checked"
     @change="({ target: { checked }}) => items[index].checked = checked"
    />
  </label>
</div>
```

If you want to show checkboxes that are checked when the form displays you could do something like this.